# Remove objects from array?

Tags: angular

I have this in my template:

```
   <div class="ui-g" *ngFor="let item of orderTrackings, let i = index;" (click)="selectItem(item,i)" [ngClass]="{'active':selectedItem == i}">
       <destinations #cpdc class="child" *ngIf="orderTrackings.length" [item]="item" [trackings]="orderTrackings" [dfp]="dataFromPopup" [groupDestinations]="groupDestinations"></destinations>
    </div>
```

Problem is that in orderTrackings array i can have multiple objects that are same completely. How can i select only one object on click and if it not exists in new array add it if it does remove it. This is my ts:

```
selectItem(item,i) {
    if(this.selectedItem.indexOf(item,i) === -1){
        this.selectedItem.push(item);
    }else{
        this.selectedItem.splice(this.selectedItem.indexOf(item,i), 1);
    }
}
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I think the item might be having some id, you can loop through the array and find if that particular item with id exists.

```
selectItem(item) {
    const itemPresent = this.selectedItem.find(t => t.id === item.id)

    if(itemPresent){
        this.selectedItem = this.selectedItem.filter(t => t.id !== item.id)
    }else{
        this.selectedItem.push(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont have id or anything uniqe for this objects...they are same

Comment: Well if you are dealing with objects, there has to be some sort of identification

Comment: i have a list of object and i can move them in other list of object where i can select them and delete them

Comment: But until you don't have any unique identification, you won't be able to do what you have asked in your question.

Comment: It will be better if it's implemented server side, but if you want to have some temp ids, you can use tools such as uuid and assign every item a unique id when initiliazing, and when you are done, you can remove the unique ids